# How do I pass the value of my onClick event to my second function?

Tags: javascript, json

Basically I have an `<input>` field where I start typing in a name. As I type, html pops up with an unordered list `<ul>` featuring names of my videos from my JSON file. What I'm trying to do is be able to click on the button, and play the video in the `<video>` player. However, "val.name" is not being passed to function g(); when I click on it.

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        var output = '<ul class="searchresults">';
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if (val.name.search(myExp) != -1) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<div>'+ val.name +'</div>';
                output += '<img src="images/'+ val.name +'.jpg" alt="'+ val.name +'" />';
                output += '<button onClick="g('+ val.name +')" >Help Me Here</button>';                     
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('#update').html(output);
    });
});


function g(e){
    $('#videoObj').remove();
    $('<video controls preload="metadata" id="videoObj" width="100%" height="720"  src="videos/'+e+'.mp4" type="video/mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen><track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="subtitles/'+e+'.vtt" ></video>').prependTo('#vholder').attr('autoplay','autoplay');  
}
```

Comment: where's the HTML you're targeting? what value IS being passed to the function?

Comment: You need quotes around the string val.name in the line that writes out the onClick handler.

Comment: Please do not construct HTML from JS strings, it only causes trouble if you forget to encode values that should be encoded. Also it is a pain to read and maintain.

Comment: @Marc - If you look at the end of my video tag, the value is being passed within it, and prependTo an ID. Not sure why it didn't wrap around.
!

Comment: @James - Thanks! I overlooked that!

Comment: @H.B. - Thanks for all your hard work and detailed description. Never seen anyone comment with such value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html string is malformed. change this

```
output += '<button onClick="g('+ val.name +')" >Help Me Here</button>';
```

to this

```
output += '<button onclick="g(\''+ val.name +'\')" >Help Me Here</button>';
```

Comment: Well, do you know who is a monkey's Uncle? LMBO...this guy right here! Thanks! Don't know how I continued to overlook this for 3 days now!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please accept the answer so it can help others as well.

Comment: How do I do that? I voted it up, but how do I accept?

Comment: there should be a green checkmark next to the question.